# JavaScript access parent window from popup windows

Tags: javascript

I am trying to code this for hours and still couldn't do it. It keep tell me "Permission Denied".

Here is what I am trying to accomplish. This pretty hard to explain please follow the example below.

For example. domain111.com and domain222.com.
When I am on domain111.com i click on the popup link , it will pop-up the domain111.com/popup.html then  it redirect me to domain222.com. On this domain222.com it will redirect to couple pages before it redirect back to domain111.com with the result. I want to send the result from domain111.com to domain111.com.

The process is like below.
Domain111-popup to-->Domain111-redirect-->Domain222-redirect xxx Domain222 pages then redirect  to-->-Domain111---SEND to parent window->Domain11

Here is my code.

File name 1.hml on **domain111.com**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function IamParent() {
        alert('I am the parent of this window')
    }
    function PopUP() {
        window.open("http://domain222.com/2.htm", 'ALpop').focus();
    }

</script>
<body>
    <a href="#void(0);" onclick="PopUP();" >Click</a>
</body>
```

File name 2.html on **domain222.com**

```
<head>
    <title></title>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://domain111.com/3.htm?Result=Yes" />
</head>
```

Filename 2.htm on **domain111.com**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   parent.IamParent(); //execute the function from the same domain111.com/1.htm
</script>
```

Please don't suggest AJAX or web request because it will not work with this case.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Parent windows in other domains are inaccessible due to a security restriction requirement in the JavaScript engines. This applies to all browsers. It is a cross-site scripting attack prevention that cannot be disabled.

Comment: At first it pop-up to the same domain the it redirect to another domain and that domain went back to the original domain.  So the last step and the first step was on the same domain.

Comment: @user359472: It's the intermediate step that disables the entire chain though. The security engine simply will now allow it. I've never even seen a reasonable work-around to this. At my company we ended up performing a DNS alias to allow the second domain to be renamed so that it would work. This is a little dicey though.

Comment: I really don't want to have the parent windows to keep checking the status using Ajax because of the performance issue. Umm I guess I have to store some id on the database and check it when the mouse re-enter the page. This probably the best solution for now.
Thanks guys